# finding total payment in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, payment

I am trying to make a program that can find the payment a user can get after entering in their hours, (5 entries in total, and must add up to 40 hours or less). Can anyone please explain this to me? I am new to visual basic and I don't know why I don't get an output.

```
' Counter-controlled repetition: Time Entry problem.
Public Class TimeEntry

    Private Sub SubmitTimeButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SubmitTimeButton.Click

        'if user entered hours
        If Enterhourstextbox.Text <= 5 Then
            ' add the hours to the TimeRecordsListBox
            TimeRecordsListBox.Items.Add(Enterhourstextbox.Text)
            Enterhourstextbox.Clear() 'clear the Enterhourstextbox
            Enterhourstextbox.Focus() ' select the Enterhourstetbox
        End If

        ' determine whether to prevent the user from entering more results
        If TimeRecordsListBox.Items.Count = 5 Then
            SubmitTimeButton.Enabled = False ' disables SubmitTimeButton
            Enterhourstextbox.Enabled = False ' disables Enterhourstextbox
            GetpaymentButton.Enabled = True ' enable GetpaymentButton
        End If

    End Sub ' submitTimeButton_Click

    ' calculates the total hours based on the hours in TimeRecordsListBox
    Private Sub GetpaymentButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GetpaymentButton.Click

        Dim hourtotal As Integer ' sum of hours entered by user
        Dim hourCounter As Integer ' counter for hours 
        Dim hour As Integer ' hour input by user
        Dim total As Integer ' payment total

        ' initialization phase
        hourtotal = 0 ' set total to zero before adding hours to it
        hourCounter = 0 ' prepare to loop

        ' processing phase
        Do While hourCounter < TimeRecordsListBox.Items.Count
            hour = TimeRecordsListBox.Items.Add(hourCounter) ' get next hour
            hourtotal += hour
            hourCounter += 1 ' add 1 to hourCounter
        Loop

        ' termination phase
        If hourCounter <= 0 Or hourCounter >= 15 Then
            getpaymentlabel.Text = hourtotal * 9
        End If

        If hourCounter <= 16 Or hourCounter >= 25 Then
            getpaymentlabel.Text = hourtotal * 13
        End If

        If hourCounter <= 26 Or hourCounter >= 40 Then
            getpaymentlabel.Text = hourtotal * 20
        End If

    End Sub ' calculateAverageButton_Click

    Private Sub CleartimeButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CleartimeButton.Click

        TimeRecordsListBox.Items.Clear() ' removes all items
        getpaymentlabel.Text = String.Empty ' enables submitResultButton
        Enterhourstextbox.Clear() ' remoces items from EnterhoursTextBox

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Your title says Java, the tags on the question says Java, but the given code certainly isn't. What do you want?

Comment: sorry guys long dayy... its is visual basic...

Comment: You should turn on Option Strict

Answer (score 1):

There is something really wrong with your **GetpaymentButton_Click** method.
Let's take a look to it.

First, You have a bunch of variables declared

- hourtotal
- hourCounter
- hour
- Total

**hourtotal**

You declare this integer at the beginning of your sub but you never assign any value to it. You only use it in your *termination phase*.

```
    ' termination phase
If hourtotal <= 0 Or hourtotal >= 15 Then
    total = hourtotal * 9
    getpaymentlabel.Text = hourtotal * 9
```

Since you never assigned anything ever to it, it's value remains **0** at all time.

This is your issue right there. You could replace

```
getpaymentlabel.Text = hourtotal * 9
```

with

```
getpaymentlabel.Text = 0 * 9
```

and it would be the same as you do not do anything to change the value of your variable.

**Total** and **hours**

These variable are assigned but never used. Then again, you could remove them entirely.

Something like this (see below) would be more likely to work. 
I re-enginered a bit but the important point is that now the hourtotal is used.

```
Private Sub GetpaymentButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim Hourtotal As Integer ' sum of hours entered by user

    ' processing phase

    For Each TimeentryValue As object In TimeRecordsListBox.Items
        Dim CurrentEntry As Integer

        If Not Integer.TryParse(TimeentryValue, CurrentEntry) Then
            Hourtotal = -1 '  If one of the entry was not an integer :( 
            Exit For
        End If

        Hourtotal += CurrentEntry
    Next

   ' termination phase

    If Hourtotal <= 0 Or Hourtotal >= 15 Then
        getpaymentlabel.Text = Hourtotal * 9
    End If
End Sub ' calculateAverageButton_Click
```

The listbox items are "object" so in addition to all that, I used

```
Integer.TryParse
```

to ensure that the listbox item was actually an integer before adding it to hourtotal. If not, then your application won't crash because you tried to add something that wasn't possible to cast into an integer to your hour total.

You might need to tweak what I gave you or not use it at all in fact. 
To correct your problem, all uou have to do is to actually increment hourtotal at some point, thing you do not do currently and the cause for your label being always **0**.

Comment: I tried your method and tried making changes to my issue but I still don't get the desired output. I updated the changes I made to the time entry problem. Can you help me find the issue again?

Comment: Do you know how to use breakpoints ? Learn how to, you will spot that kind of error instantly. (Put one in your processing phase and look at the variables)

Comment: Change TimeRecordsListBox.Items.Add(hourCounter) in the processing phace for TimeRecordsListBox.Items(hourCounter).Does it help ? You want to get the value, not add another one. It should solve that issue.